# Abstraction of a proton in cycloheptatriene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

So, whenever there is abstraction of H<sup>+</sup> by an acid-base reaction, I see that the proton on the sp3-hybridized carbon is taken. Why is this if you take into account that vinylic hydrogens are more acidic?

Also, on a sidenote, what is the hybridization state of a carbon in a C=C double bond where the vinylic proton was removed by a base?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean transfer of hydride, i.e. oxidation to the tropylium cation?

Comment: Actually Abel, the tropylium cation is drawn. But the anion with the abstraction of the proton only on the sp3 carbon is also shown (Cycloheptatrienyl anion). It was an exercise where we had to say whether the compounds were aromatic or not. Could we make such compound from acid-base reactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pKa for a vinylic proton is ~ 43, the pKa for propene is ~ 40, and the pKa for 1,4-pentadiene is ~ 35.  Consequently it's not the vinylic protons that are the most acidic, it's the allylic ones.  Now the question whether tropylium anion is aromatic/antiaromatic is *[complicated](http://web.utk.edu/~rmagid/360antiaromatic.pdf)*.

Comment: Abel, are you saying that an acid would rather rip apart a hydrogen from the sp3 carbon in the propene?

Comment: If you think about it, is CH3:- not a much stronger base than CH2=CH:-? So, it is the CH2=CH2 that is the stronger acid.

Comment: In the allyl anion the charge is delocalized over all three carbons.  In saturated hydrocarbons it's confined to a specific carbon.

Comment: Okay, so in this particular molecule (Cycloheptatrienyl anion), the abstracted hydrogen will always come from the sp3 carbon.

Comment: And in the case of propene, the hydrogen will come from the sp3 too. Why? Because although the double bond is more acidic if we look at it individually, the possibility of removing the hydrogen from the sp3 carbon adds resonance, which further stabilizes the compound than abstracting an H from the double bond.

Comment: Please say yes if all my reasoning is correct.

Comment: I think you are correct in saying this,